# Android html Mail sending

Tags: android, html, email

I have used the following code for sending a mail from my android app.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Thai Hostess");
String emailText = "<html><body><p>Hi there,</p><p>Your friend wants you to watch this video. <a href='http://TEST.com/Default.aspx?lang=eng&item=2'>Click here</a> to watch the video.</p></body></html>";
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailText));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"), 1);
```

The code is calling the mailing service properly and the user gets two options i.e. Email and Google Mail. If I chose Google mail, the text is appearing in the mailing software and I can send the mail and receive it in proper format. But if we chose Email, then also the text appears properly(with the link mentioned in the text), but if I send the mail, the received mail does not have the link. I have test in different mail id of different standard mail service provider. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: I suppose the " in your URL http://TEST.com/Default.aspx?lang=eng&item="2 is a typo - because otherwise this wouldn't compile.

Comment: no it is not that actually. I wrote it like that only, it was something else in the original code.

Comment: care to share what was the problem, as I have the same issue. The same email with an html anchor sends fine in Android's GMail app, but not with the "Email" app

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitly want to send html's anchor ()?
In my application I also send a link via email, but I simply send http://site.com/abcd, which most email applications already understand as a http link

Comment: I actually send an explicit anchor tag so that link is present behind some text.